# Link in Div affects text outside of the Div

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am displaying an image link to Facebook chat. The link is also affecting text in the same column below but outside of the div? I only want the Image to link nothing else! Thanks for any help!

```
<div><a href="https://test.com"><img src="https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/messenger-button.png" width="300px" height="auto"></div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjRvV.png)

Comment: You’re missing the closing tag for the <a> element

Comment: Thank you... So sorry! tired eyes!

Comment: I still do that kind of thing occasionally after 20 years of doing it. Don’t feel bad 

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close the `<a>` tag after the `<img>` tag! So it extends to wherever the browser decides to automatically correct this error.

Make that:

```
<div><a href="https://test.com"><img src="https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/messenger-button.png" width="300px" height="auto"></a></div>
```

Comment: Wow... How stupid! I have done that but its still doing it! lol It might be a caching issue wordpress?

Comment: Thank you!!!! I promise to double check in the future!